# Laravel route query get email address from query value instead of key

Tags: laravel, url, routes

I have encountered an issue regarding Laravel 8 routes.
And I am unable to find a solution to this problem.

For example, I have this route format in Laravel:

```
$domain/password_reset?$email
```

Where it will look like this:

```
http://test-website.com/password_reset?test@gmail.com
```

I am aware that query parameters have `?key=value` format. However in my case, the provided route format is what is expected (by client). Not the conventional key=value way. Also, the url link is clicked from an email. Wherein the link in the email uses the exact route format given (not url-encoded).

The sample request query that is fetched in the controller is as follows:
[image]

If you would notice, the email became a key (which is expected). And since it is a key, `.` has been changed to `_`. Instead of `gmail.com` it became `gmail_com`.

Would there be a better solution to get the exact email address from the url (not url-encoded) in this route format? Hopefully someone can help me with this. Thank you very much in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

You should get the request query and parse it yourself:

```php
[$path, $query] = explode('?',$request->fullUrl())
```

In the exemple above `$query` should hold everything after `?` on the URL.

Alternativelly you can just get the key of the array you already have:

```php
$email = array_keys($request->all())[0]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! I have tried using the same solution like yours which is in my case I tried `$email = array_key_first($requestData);` and it got the email as expected. However, the problem is that the email has been changed. Since it is an array key, `.` has been changed to `_`. Instead of `gmail.com` it became `gmail_com`. Kindly refer to the screenshot in my question. Thank you~